# sed repetition-operator operand invalid *****

Tags: sed

I have text files that contain `*****` in some locations.  I need to replace the `*****` with `9.999`.  This obviously came from some formatting error, but I do not have the program that created the files I now have to work with.  I tried using the following command in csh:

```
sed -i "" 's/*****/9.999/g' *.dat
```

However, as I expected, I get the following error message:

```
sed: 1: "s/*****/9.999/g": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

I'm assuming this is because `*****` is considered a special operator or something like that, but I can't figure out how to exempt them while using the sed command.

Does anyone have a hint that could help?

Comment: The first step to try is reading the manual; if that's too time consuming, use a backslash as the 'escape' operator (so `s/\*\*\*\*\*/9.999/g` for example) as it is a … universal is too strong, but very common isn't … very common way to escape special characters, especially with older programs that originated on Unix, like `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -E 's/\*{5}/9.999/g'  file
```